# r - Comparing User Accounts across different Events

Tags: r

I have multiple data frames each consiting of one variable (column) and a few thousand observations (rows). The character values are screen names of twitter accounts that have been generated for a specific event/time_span.

```
tweets <- parseTweets("Event_X.json", verbose = FALSE)
screen_names <- tweets$screen_names
names.df <- as.data.frame(screen_names)
names_unique <- unique(names.df)
head(names_unique)

          Screen_Names_Event_X 
    1     Account_A 
    2     Account_B 
    9     Account_C 
   10     Account_D
  ...     ...
```

Another data frame example:

```
          Screen_Names_Event_Z
    1     Account_F
    2     Account_Z
    7     Account_P
    12    Account_A
    ...   ...
```

Now I would like to create a matrix or data frame to find out which account was active across different events. I am not quite sure how to do this. I am looking for a solution like this:

```
  Screen_Names   Event_X    Event_Y    Event_Z
  Account_A      TRUE       FALSE      TRUE
  Account_B      TRUE       TRUE       FALSE
  Account_F      FALSE      TRUE       FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to do a complete working code as your exemple is not reproductible. But you should creat a data.frame with one column for the name and the other with just a one for exemple.

```
data_frame_1 <- data.frame(acc_name = c("Account_1","Account_2","Account_10"),check1 =1)
data_frame_2 <- data.frame(acc_name = c("Account_3","Account_1","Account_4","Account_10"),check2 =1)
data_frame_3 <- data.frame(acc_name = c("Account_6","Account_7","Account_2","Account_10"),check3 =1)

data_frame_all <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), list(data_frame_1, data_frame_2, data_frame_3))
final <- data.frame(data_frame_all$acc_name, !is.na(data_frame_all[,colnames(data_frame_all)!="acc_name"]))
final

  data_frame_all.acc_name check1 check2 check3
1               Account_1   TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
2              Account_10   TRUE   TRUE   TRUE
3               Account_2   TRUE  FALSE   TRUE
4               Account_3  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
5               Account_4  FALSE   TRUE  FALSE
6               Account_6  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
7               Account_7  FALSE  FALSE   TRUE
```

Edit :
To make it work with your code the idea is to creat data frame using your account list like this:

```
tweets <- parseTweets("Event_X.json", verbose = FALSE)
screen_names <- tweets$screen_names
names.df <- as.data.frame(screen_names)
names_unique <- unique(names.df)
data_frame_1 <- data.frame(acc_name = names_unique, Event_X = 1)
```

Do the same for every event then use the rest of the first code to merge the data frame.

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer. Since I will be dealing with several thousand screen_names from each data.frame, is there maybe an easier way than using the string c(.....) ?

Comment: I though you already had the data.frame containing the strings. Maybe I didn't fully understand your goal?

Can't you just creat:
data_frame1 <- data.frame(acc_name =  Screen_Names_Event_X, check = 1)